# how can i calculate A from this equation?

Tags: math, equation

```
((A*55)/(A+1815))+4=B
```

eg.:

```
((1000*55)/(1000+1815))+4=23.53819
```

How can i calculate from

```
23.53819 1000?
```

A and B are variables.

Sry for my bad english ;)
Thanks any help!

Comment: I think you have misunderstood this web site - we do not do basic algebra homework

Comment: This type of questions is good for sites like [socratic](socratic.com).

Comment: This is junior high school algebra.  Your English is fine; it's your math that is in poor shape.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's junior high school algebra.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: image for solution]

Just follow the steps described before. The goal is to manipulate the expression to get all terms containing the variable to be solved for on one side.

Comment: Have you helped this person in his education?

Answer (score -1):

You Have to First do what ever present in Brackets then Division, Multiplication and then Addition and Subtraction.
For any equation you have to follow the sequence.

Hope this helps